# Does stl map end iterator requires mutex protection or I can unlock before?

Tags: c++, optimization, concurrency, stl, mutex

I have this code:

```cpp
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string> data;
...

ContextMutex context_mutex( _mutex );
auto pair_iterator = data.find( std::make_pair(some, thing));

if(pair_iterator == data.end())
{
    context_mutex.unlock();
    // do some logging without using pair_iterator
}
context_mutex.unlock();
```

On this code, I only release the mutex for my STL container after checking if `pair_iterator == data.end()`. I wonder if I can release the mutex before checking `pair_iterator == data.end()` because I do not use the `pair_iterator` or any of its contents as I just print a log if the object if found.

On this case, can I release the mutex before checking the condition `pair_iterator == data.end()` (as the following example) or the access to the `data.end()` needs to be protected by a mutex too (as done in the first example)?

```cpp
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::string> data;
...

ContextMutex context_mutex( _mutex );
auto pair_iterator = data.find( std::make_pair(some, thing));
context_mutex.unlock();

if(pair_iterator == data.end())
{
    // do some logging without using pair_iterator
}
```

Related:

1. [Iterator invalidation rules for C++ containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules-for-c-containers)
2. [Why do C++ STL container begin and end functions return iterators by value rather than by constant reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097778/why-do-c-stl-container-begin-and-end-functions-return-iterators-by-value-rathe)
3. [STL iterator revalidation for end (past-the-end) iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53336685/stl-iterator-revalidation-for-end-past-the-end-iterator)

Comment: Advise : use std::mutex and std::unique_lock. I don't think releasing the mutex early is a good idea. Imagine you want to use the iterator to modify or lookup data and another thread does something to the map that invalidates the iterator then you still have race conditions. What I would do is get the data out of the map within the lock (copy it) then unlock and then use the copied data for logging (which can be quite slow).

Comment: If you don't protect it, then an element could be added to the map before the if statement is executed, giving you a false positive.

Comment: Or an element removed, even the element that's just been found. In fact, after the mutex is unlocked the remaining iterator is now completely useless.

Comment: Re: "I do not use the `pair_iterator`" -- but you **do** use it: `if(pair_iterator == data.end()) ...`. So, no, you can't unlock before doing the test.

Comment: You can do `bool is_in_map = (data.find( std::make_pair(some, thing)) != data.end()); context_mutex.unlock(); if (!is_in_map)...`

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is, that the end iterator will not be invalidated on insertion or deletion. Thus, it would be safe to compare an iterator to the map's end iterator in a multi-threaded environment.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432796/1531765

> Iterators in (multi)sets and (multi)maps won't be invalidated in
> insertions and deletions and thus comparing .end() against previous
> stored values of .end() will always yield true.